# Get function with a switch statement

Tags: javascript, express

Trying to get the proper sql statement but it does not work:

```
function getsql (key) {
    switch (key) {
        case 1:
            return 'SELECT * FROM main WHERE 1';
            break;
        case 2:
            return 'SELECT * FROM location WHERE 1';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
};

operations.get('/filter/:key', function (req, res) {
    var sql = getsql(parseInt(req.params.key));
    db.query(sql, function (error, results) {
        res.json(results);
    })
})
```

I don't know what to do, please help me.

Comment: em, Can you at least explain what your question is?

Comment: please click on the link above to see the code. Help me out please. Trying to use the number generated to fetch the right sql statement but it is giving me undefined as the result.

Comment: trying to fetch data from database but i need the right sql statement from the function getsql, when i run the code and test it with postman, it produces no result

Comment: Dude, no one will understand your question unless you actually explain what is wrong, what is the problem and what have you done to solve it. 

Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Could you please post the code as actual code on here rather than as an image?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz i have all the necessary connections. i have connected to my database alright and i want to make a query and retrieve some data from the database. I am using express node and i have my get function. I also have a switch function which i have called inside the get function. Now base on the number key the user types at the end of the url, i generate the right sql statement from the switch function getsql. Now the problem is that the variable sql is not assigned the right statement

Answer (score 1):

Your `key` is a string, convert it to Int. `parseInt(key, 10)`.

```
function getSQL(key) {
    switch (key) {
        case 1:
            return `SELECT * FROM main WHERE 1`;
        case 2:
            return `SELECT * FROM location WHERE 1`;
        default:
            return ``;
    }
}

router.get(`/filter/:key`, (req, res) => {
    const key = parseInt(req.params.key, 10);
    const sql = getSQL(key);
    res.send(`The SQL text: ${sql}`);
});
```

[Working demo](https://repl.it/@sultan99/express-router)

Comment: @AwudiEricOkyere I have applied a link of working demo, after starting the server open url https://express-router--sultan99.repl.co/filter/1

Comment: @AwudiEricOkyere later when you get the correct answer don't forget to mark it and to vote.